# ElasticSearch: Filter on deeply nested data

Tags: elasticsearch

Our data is stored in MongoDB 2.4.8, and indexed to ElasticSearch 0.90.7 using the ElasticSearch MongoDB River 1.7.3.

Our data indexes correctly, and I can successfully search the fields we want to search. But I also need to filter on permission - of course we only want to return results the calling user can actually read.

In the code on our server, I have the calling user's authorizations as an array, for example:

```
[ "Role:REGISTERED_USER", "Account:52c74b25da06f102c90d52f4", "Role:USER", "Group:52cb057cda06ca463e78f0d7" ]
```

An example of the unit data we're searching follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52dffbd6da06422559386f7d"),
    "content" : "various stuff",
    "ownerId" : ObjectId("52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"),
    "acls" : [
        {
            "accessMap" : {},
            "sourceClass" : "com.bulb.learn.domain.units.PublishedPageUnit",
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("52dffbd6da06422559386f7d")
        },
        {
            "accessMap" : {
                "Role:USER" : {
                    "allow" : [
                        "READ"
                    ]
                },
                "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf" : {
                    "allow" : [
                        "CREATE",
                        "READ",
                        "UPDATE",
                        "DELETE",
                        "GRANT"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "sourceClass" : "com.bulb.learn.domain.units.CompositeUnit",
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("52dffb54da06422559386f57")
        }
    ]
}
```

In the sample data above, I have replaced all the searchable content with
 `"content" : "various stuff"`

The authorization data is in the "acls" array. The filter I need to write would do the following (in English):

```
pass all units where the "acls" array
contains an "accessMap" object
that contains a property whose name is one of the user's authorization strings
and whose "allow" property contains "READ"
and whose "deny" property does not contain "READ"
```

In the example above, the user has "Role:USER" authorization, and this unit has an accessMap that has "Role:USER", which contains "allow", which contains "READ", and "Role:USER" contains no "deny". So this unit would pass the filter.

I am not seeing how to write a filter for this using ElasticSearch.

I get the impression that there are two ways to deal with nested arrays like this: "nested", or "has_child" (or "has_parent").

We are reluctant to use the "nested" filter because it apparently requires that the whole block be re-indexed when any of the data changes. Searchable content and authorization data can change at any time, in response to user actions.

It looks to me as though in order to use "has_child" or "has_parent", the authorization data would have to be separate from the unit data (in a different collection?), and when a node is indexed, it would have to have its parent or child specified. I don't know whether the ElasticSearch MongoDB River is capable of doing this.

So is this even possible? Or should we rearrange the authorization data?

Comment: I'd use separate indexes for the different levels of access, and bump access control to a proxy on top of ES.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Thanks, @Alex Brasetvik, your suggestion to make the subject IDs data instead of keys, and your explanation that nested is "join-per-update", but parent-child is "join-per-query", were most helpful.

I see that I would have to "un-nest" the data to use the parent-child approach, and we prefer to keep the authorization data nested.

I don't understand what you meant by "It wouldn't work to have two nested with a bool in it."

Here's how I refactored the data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52dffbd6da06422559386f7d"),
    "content" : "various stuff",
    "ownerId" : ObjectId("52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"),
    "accessMaps" : [
        {
            "sourceClass" : "com.bulb.learn.domain.units.PublishedPageUnit",
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("52dffbd6da06422559386f7d")
        },
        {
            "allow" : {
                "CREATE" : [
                    "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"
                ],
                "READ" : [
                    "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf",
                    "Role:USER"
                ],
                "UPDATE" : [
                    "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"
                ],
                "DELETE" : [
                    "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"
                ],
                "GRANT" : [
                    "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"
                ]
            },
            "deny" : {},
            "sourceClass" : "com.bulb.learn.domain.units.CompositeUnit",
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("52dffb54da06422559386f57")
        }
    ]
}
```

The new mapping looks like this:

```
{
  "unit": {
    "properties": {
      "accessMaps": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "allow": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "CREATE": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
              "DELETE": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
              "GRANT": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
              "READ": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
              "UPDATE": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              }
            } 
          },    
          "deny": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "CREATE": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
              "DELETE": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
              "GRANT": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
              "READ": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
              "UPDATE": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              } 
            }   
          },    
          "sourceClass": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "sourceId": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the filtered query looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "accessMaps.allow",
              "filter": {
                "terms": {
                  "accessMaps.allow.READ": [
                    "Role:REGISTERED_USER",
                    "Account:52e6a361da06e4eb64172519",
                    "Role:USER",
                    "Group:52cb057cda06ca463e78f0d7"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "accessMaps.deny",
              "filter": {
                "terms": {
                  "accessMaps.deny.READ": [
                    "Role:REGISTERED_USER",
                    "Account:52e6a361da06e4eb64172519",
                    "Role:USER",
                    "Group:52cb057cda06ca463e78f0d7"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The biggest problem I had was figuring out how to use the "path" property in the nested filter, and that the field name in the terms filter must be fully-qualified. I wish ElasticSearch would put more effort into their documentation.

Comment: You seriously took someone else's answer, worked it into your own, and just took credit for it yourself?  WTF?

Answer (score 10):

You need to restructure your data a bit.

Having a value in a key is problematic with Elasticsearch. It'll end up as a separate field, and you'll have an ever-growing mapping and consequently also cluster state.

You probably want to have accessMap be a list of objects, with what's currently a key as a value. Then, it'll have to be nested. Otherwise, you have no way of knowing which accessMap the matching allow belongs to.

Whether the ACLs should be nested (resulting in two levels of nesting) or a parent-child depends a bit on how often you update the various objects. By having them as nested docs on the object, you pay the cost of joining every time something's updated. If you do parent-child, you'll need to pay the join-cost on every search.

This quickly gets complicated, so I prepared a simplified runnable example you can play with: https://www.found.no/play/gist/8582654

Note how the `nested`- and `bool`-filters are, erm, nested. It wouldn't work to have two nested with a bool in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "acls": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "accessMap": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "allow": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                },
                                "deny": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                },
                                "key": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'


# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type","_id":1}}
{"acls":[{"accessMap":[{"key":"Role:USER","allow":["READ"]},{"key":"Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf","allow":["READ","UPDATE"]}]}]}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type","_id":2}}
{"acls":[{"accessMap":[{"key":"Role:USER","allow":["READ"]},{"key":"Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf","deny":["READ","UPDATE"]}]}]}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type","_id":3}}
{"acls":[{"accessMap":[{"key":"Role:USER","allow":["READ"]},{"key":"Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf","allow":["READ","UPDATE"]}]}]}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "acls",
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "acls.accessMap",
                                    "filter": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "allow": "READ"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "terms": {
                                                        "key": [
                                                            "Role:USER",
                                                            "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "must_not": {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "acls.accessMap",
                                    "filter": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "deny": "READ"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "terms": {
                                                        "key": [
                                                            "Role:USER",
                                                            "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

For completeness, here is a similar example for the parent-child-approach: https://www.found.no/play/gist/8586840

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
        "acl": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "document"
            },
            "properties": {
                "acls": {
                    "properties": {
                        "accessMap": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "key": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                },
                                "allow": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                },
                                "deny": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'


# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"document","_id":1}}
{"title":"Doc 1"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"acl","_parent":1}}
{"acls":[{"accessMap":[{"key":"Role:USER","allow":["READ"]},{"key":"Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf","allow":["READ","UPDATE"]}]}]}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"document","_id":2}}
{"title":"Doc 2"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"acl","_parent":2}}
{"acls":[{"accessMap":[{"key":"Role:USER","allow":["READ"]},{"key":"Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf","deny":["READ","UPDATE"]}]}]}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "has_child": {
                    "type": "acl",
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "nested": {
                                        "path": "acls.accessMap",
                                        "filter": {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "must": [
                                                    {
                                                        "terms": {
                                                            "key": [
                                                                "Role:USER",
                                                                "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "allow": "READ"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "must_not": [
                                {
                                    "nested": {
                                        "path": "acls.accessMap",
                                        "filter": {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "must": [
                                                    {
                                                        "terms": {
                                                            "key": [
                                                                "Role:USER",
                                                                "Account:52d96bfada0695fcbdb41daf"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "deny": "READ"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: I updated the answer to also include a similar example with a parent-child-mapping.

Comment: One important simplification is possible because I don't actually care which accessMap the allow or deny comes from - if there is ANY matching deny, the filter must fail, else if there is ANY matching allow, the filter must succeed. Does this allow us to remove the nesting entirely?

Comment: That wouldn't work, as if a DENY existed for a group the user is not a member of, you'd still get a match.